# AJAX / jQuery $.get method works, but $.post does not

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Yesterday I made my first successful AJAX call using this function which was linked to a button click event.

```
function function1(){
  $.get("ajax/calendar.php", function(data){
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
  });
};
```

Now I would like to use the *$.post* method so that I can pass in 2 values that I had simply hard coded when I used the *$.get* method.

Here are my inputs and submit button:

```
<div ... >
  <div ... >
    <div ... >
      <span ... >From:</span>
      <input ... name="strDte">
    </div>      
    <div ...>
      <span ... >To: </span>
      <input ... name="endDte">
    </div>                
  </div>
  <div ... >
    <button type="submit" onclick="dateRange(strDte, endDte)">OK</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I created a similar function to my $.get method:

```
function dateRange(startD, endD){
  $.post("ajax/calendar.php", {startDate : strDte, endDate : endDte}, function(data){
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
  });
};
```

and I updated "ajax/calendar.php" to accept the value that were hard coded before:

```
$formStartDate = $_POST['startDate'];
$formEndDate = $_POST['endDate'];
```

**EDIT:** my console is telling me that the parameters are not being recognized by function call in the event handler.

**Does anyone see what my issue is?** I'd also love some design suggestions if you think there is a better way of achieving this function.

Comment: The PHP you've supplied so far doesn't output anything. What makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: You do not cancel the form submission....

Comment: @epascarello — There's no form though

Comment: @Quentin well there can be, it is only a small sample of code...

Comment: I'm not showing the output but it did work with the $.get method. I just hardcoded the 2 variable in the question. Cancel the form? there is no form; just 2 inputs and a button.

Comment: @epascarello — It's a sample of code too small to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Quentin or maybe not

Comment: @Quentin In the future, how can I make this question better?

Comment: @epascarello In the future, how can I make this question better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing up form elements, not the values of the elements. You have wrong variable names.

Give the inputs ids

```
<input ... name="strDte" id="strDte">
<input ... name="endDte" id="endDte">
```

Update the JavaScript to reference the value.

```
 function dateRange(startD, endD){
  $.post("ajax/calendar.php", {startDate : startD.value, endDate : endD.value}, function(data){
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
  });
};
```

You are using bad practice by referencing elements directly by their name/id and inline events are not the greatest thing to use. You should use getElementById or querySelector to reference the elements.

Answer (score 2):

The variable names used in your function definition should match the names you use within your function. That is

```
{startDate : strDte, endDate : endDte}
```

should be

```
{startDate : startD, endDate : endD}
```

I suggest you play around with this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/3657/

It is using a service from JSFiddle to echo back what you send to it. I changed the AJAX call to use $.post() instead of $.ajax() since this is the function you are playing with! :)

Some additional tips when learning such technologies. Always check with your browsers developers' tools. There you can follow the request being sent to your backend and catch any errors. The "Network" and "Console" (on Chrome dev tools, but Firefox has similar, too) tabs are your friends in this case!

Enjoy and happy learning!

Answer (score 1):

The variable names you pass into the function must pass those you use in the `data` parameter of `$.post()`. You're passing:

`startD` but trying to use `strDte` .. and
`endD`   but trying to use `endDte` .... `strDte` and `endDte` are not defined anywhere.

Try this instead:

```
function dateRange(startDate, endDate){
  $.post("ajax/calendar.php", {startDate : startDate, endDate : endDate}, function(data){
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
  });
};
```

**UPDATE**
Now that I know where the confusion was coming from the best approach is one that allows you to separate, clearly, your JS from your HTML.

Per your request for suggestions,  here's how:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#my_form').on('submit', function(event) {
        //stop the form from submitting via default submission
        event.preventDefault();
        //get form data
        var formData = $(this).serialize();
        //see what the data looks like
        console.log( formData );
        //make ajax call
        $.post('ajax/calendar.php', formData, function(data){
            $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my_form">
  <div><label for="strDte">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="startDate" id="strDte"/>
  </div>
  <div><label for="endDte">End Date:</label>
    <input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDte"/>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I actually started with this and changed the variable names to see if that was the issue. I just plugged it in again, but it doesn't work. Thanks though.

Comment: **"Doesn't work"** could mean anything. It would be helpful if you would check if there are any errors. Developer tools are your best bet here.

Comment: the console is telling me that the parameters are not being recognized in the button event-handler: *onclick="dateRange(strDte, endDte)*

Comment: @NateMay please see my suggestion on how you can improve your application.

Comment: I've never worked with serialize() before. Seems like it will make things difficult to work with on the PHP side. No?

Comment: Also, how can I make this question better? I don't know how to avoid these down votes yet.

Comment: No, your PHP will be just fine. .... Most people, even newbies, consider the inconsistencies I pointed out as mistakes one should not make. Just avoid such in your next question and all will be well. You may also add an explanatory update to this question.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not using a form, you should be declaring your button to be a button type to show that you are not submitting a form.

```
<button id="submitBtn" type="button">OK</button>
```

Your problem is that you are not supplying an **id** attribute for your `<input>` tags. `name` is only used in forms. Change your `<input>` tags to be

```
<input id="strDte">
<input id="endDte">
```

Then in your script, you can use

```
$("#submitBtn").click(function () {
    var start = $("#strDte").val();
    var end = $("#endDte").val();
    $.post("ajax/calendar.php", { startDate: start, endDate: end }, function (data) {
        $("#ajaxResponse").html(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a simple ajax post you can play around with...

```
<input id="start_date" name="startDate" />
<input id="end_date" name="endDate" />
<button type="submit" id="submit_dates">Submit</button>

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("button#submit_dates").click(function(){
       var startDate = $("#start_date").val(); 
       var endDate = $("#end_date").val(); 
       $.ajax({
           type:'POST',
           url:'ajax/calendar.php',
           data:"startDate=" + startDate + "&endDate=" + endDate,
           success:function(data) {
               if(data) {   
                   $("#ajaxResponse").html(data);
               } else {
                   // no response
               }
           }
       });
    });

});
```